# Pyspark function to minus previous rows

Tags: pyspark

I'm encountering an issue when it comes to applying a lag/windows function to entire dataframe on a condition.

I want to minus the previous rows value(value1), with the current rows value(value2), from week 2 onwards.

Here is my data:

'''

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 0, 5),
    (3, 0, 10),
    (4, 0, 20),
    (5, 0, 30),
    (6, 0, 40)
]
columns = ["week", "value1", "value2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

'''

Here is my logic to do the calc:

'''

```
w=Window.orderBy("week")
                          
df2 = df.withColumn('value1',
                    f.when((f.col('week') > 1),
                           f.lag(df['value1']).over(w) - df['value2'] 
                          ).otherwise(
                        f.col('value1')
                    )
                   )
```

'''

This does not work across the whole dataframe, it only applies to the first row.

as you can see here:
[image]

E.g. Week 3's value1 should be (-4) - (10) which would equal -14

I want the previous weeks value1 to minus the current weeks value 2. The lag seems to not carry through the entire dataframe

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: please provide dataframe that doenst work. Dataframe you provided seems to work with your code

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `sum` window function. you will get expected result.

```
w=Window.orderBy("week")
                          
df2 = df.withColumn('value1',
                    f.when((f.col('week') > 1),
                           f.sum(f.lag(df['value1']).over(w) - df['value2']).over(w)
                          ).otherwise(
                        f.col('value1')
                    )
                   )
```

```
+----+------+------+
|week|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|1   |1     |1     |
|2   |-4    |5     |
|3   |-14   |10    |
|4   |-34   |20    |
|5   |-64   |30    |
|6   |-104  |40    |
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: Please except answer if this is worked. thanks!

Comment: how do I reverse this to have value2 - the lagged value 1? I tried changing the order of your logic but it starts adding instead...I'd appreciate the help!